# about Sobolev imbedding theorem and dual sapce question

Tags: sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $D$ be an open and bounded subset of domain $\Omega$, let $f$ be a distribution on $\Omega$. Show that there is an integer $k$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $D$ is in $H^{-k}(D)$.

The hint is use the the fact the distribution is locally of finite order and the sobolev embedding theorem.